# How to deal with duplicate records when grouping in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a large dataset that includes race results for elections. I am trying to get the total precincts reporting vs. the total precincts.

An example of the dataFrame called precincts:

```
Race          officeID   CandidateId  total_votes  locationID    precinct_name
Mayor         10         705            20         101           111 
Mayor         10         805            30         101           888
Mayor         10         705            20         101           ##ABS 
Mayor         10         805            30         201           222
Mayor         10         705            20         201           888 
Mayor         10         805            30         201           ##ABS
Mayor         10         705            20         301           333 
Mayor         10         805            30         301           888
Mayor         10         805            30         301           ##ABS
```

I use this to get the vote totals and I apply a function to the group to get the number of precincts reporting and the total number.

```
def get_precincts(prec):
        reported = {'reported':prec.total_votes.count(),
                    'total': prec.total_votes.notnull().count()}
        return reported

precincts = precincts.groupby(['officeId','precinct_name'], as_index=False).total_votes.sum()

# Apply the get_results function to build the district reporting data
precincts_reporting = precincts.groupby(['officeId']).apply(get_precincts)
```

This works great, but if there are duplicate precinctIDs, it doesn't count the number of unique precincts. So to handle all of the #ABS duplicate, I just replace them, like so:

```
precincts['precinct_name'] = precincts['precinct_name'].replace('##ABS', str(precincts['locationID']) + 'ABS')
```

But this doesn't solve the problem of duplicate PrecinctIDs - of which there are many - impossible to do a find and replace on every exception.

EDIT: I found the error happens before I use the .count() function. I am grouping the duplicate precincts before I count them, so I need to replace the duplicate precinct_name before I count them.

Comment: Have you tried [`value_counts()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas.Series.value_counts)?

Comment: Further investigating shows that the duplication occurs in the groupby function here:

precincts = precincts.groupby(['officeId','precinct_name'], as_index=False).total_votes.sum()

So I need to create unique precinct names prior to counting anything. And yeah, I tried value_counts() = which does the same thing because I've already grouped the duplicate values.